# xmlns attribute causes xpath queries to fail

Tags: xml, r, xslt

When the root element has the attribute xmlns set to a (non-functioning) URI "http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2", then xpath queries fail. Without that attribute, xpath queries work as expected.

The following two blocks is a minimal working example of the problem

```
foo <- xmlParse(file='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TrainingCenterDatabase>
<Activities>
<Activity Sport="Other">
<Id>2013-08-31T09:01:43Z</Id>
<Lap StartTime="2013-08-31T09:01:43Z">
<TotalTimeSeconds>1928.82</TotalTimeSeconds>
<DistanceMeters>11250.1543</DistanceMeters>
<MaximumSpeed>15.6822205</MaximumSpeed>
<Calories>631</Calories>
<AverageHeartRateBpm><Value>126</Value></AverageHeartRateBpm>
<MaximumHeartRateBpm><Value>151</Value></MaximumHeartRateBpm>
<Intensity>Active</Intensity>
<TriggerMethod>Manual</TriggerMethod>
<Track><Trackpoint>
  <Time>2013-08-31T09:01:43Z</Time>
  <Position><LatitudeDegrees>57.91393099</LatitudeDegrees><LongitudeDegrees>11.77463514</LongitudeDegrees></Position>
  <AltitudeMeters>55.4130859</AltitudeMeters>
  <DistanceMeters>0.00000000</DistanceMeters>
  <HeartRateBpm><Value>77</Value></HeartRateBpm>
</Trackpoint></Track></Lap></Activity></Activities></TrainingCenterDatabase>
')
xpathSApply(foo,'//*/Time',xmlValue)
[1] "2013-08-31T09:01:43Z"
```

And the non-working version

```
foo <- xmlParse(file='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TrainingCenterDatabase xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2">
<Activities>
<Activity Sport="Other">
<Id>2013-08-31T09:01:43Z</Id>
<Lap StartTime="2013-08-31T09:01:43Z">
<TotalTimeSeconds>1928.82</TotalTimeSeconds>
<DistanceMeters>11250.1543</DistanceMeters>
<MaximumSpeed>15.6822205</MaximumSpeed>
<Calories>631</Calories>
<AverageHeartRateBpm><Value>126</Value></AverageHeartRateBpm>
<MaximumHeartRateBpm><Value>151</Value></MaximumHeartRateBpm>
<Intensity>Active</Intensity>
<TriggerMethod>Manual</TriggerMethod>
<Track><Trackpoint>
  <Time>2013-08-31T09:01:43Z</Time>
  <Position><LatitudeDegrees>57.91393099</LatitudeDegrees><LongitudeDegrees>11.77463514</LongitudeDegrees></Position>
  <AltitudeMeters>55.4130859</AltitudeMeters>
  <DistanceMeters>0.00000000</DistanceMeters>
  <HeartRateBpm><Value>77</Value></HeartRateBpm>
</Trackpoint></Track></Lap></Activity></Activities></TrainingCenterDatabase>
')
xpathSApply(foo,'//*/Time',xmlValue)
list()
```

My understanding is that the xml data was generated with this [xslt-file](http://svn.camrdale.org/doc/training/gmn2tcx.xslt), and it validates against this [xsd-scheme](http://svn.camrdale.org/doc/training/tcx.xsd), and that these two sources could be used instead of the non functioning link to http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2 . I used [this-bash-script](http://svn.camrdale.org/doc/training/gmn2tcx) toghether with data from a garmin forerunner 305 to create the xml data.

The easy way out would be to tell xmlParse() from the R package XML to ignore xmln attribute. How do I do that?

Another route would be to change the content of the xlmns attribute to something that works What would be needed in that case, and can the xsd-scheme and or the xslt-file help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a namespace argument to `xpathSApply` and adjust your xpath appropriately:

```
foo <- xmlParse(file='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TrainingCenterDatabase xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2">
<Activities>
<Activity Sport="Other">
<Id>2013-08-31T09:01:43Z</Id>
<Lap StartTime="2013-08-31T09:01:43Z">
<TotalTimeSeconds>1928.82</TotalTimeSeconds>
<DistanceMeters>11250.1543</DistanceMeters>
<MaximumSpeed>15.6822205</MaximumSpeed>
<Calories>631</Calories>
<AverageHeartRateBpm><Value>126</Value></AverageHeartRateBpm>
<MaximumHeartRateBpm><Value>151</Value></MaximumHeartRateBpm>
<Intensity>Active</Intensity>
<TriggerMethod>Manual</TriggerMethod>
<Track><Trackpoint>
  <Time>2013-08-31T09:01:43Z</Time>
  <Position><LatitudeDegrees>57.91393099</LatitudeDegrees><LongitudeDegrees>11.77463514</LongitudeDegrees></Position>
  <AltitudeMeters>55.4130859</AltitudeMeters>
  <DistanceMeters>0.00000000</DistanceMeters>
  <HeartRateBpm><Value>77</Value></HeartRateBpm>
</Trackpoint></Track></Lap></Activity></Activities></TrainingCenterDatabase>
')
xpathSApply(foo,'//*/ns:Time',xmlValue
            , namespaces = c(ns = "http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2"))


> xpathSApply(foo,'//*/ns:Time',xmlValue
+             , namespaces = c(ns = "http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2"))
[1] "2013-08-31T09:01:43Z"
```

Comment: Thank you @jdharrison, for solving the problem. So, the non-functioning URL did not matter at all, it is just an arbitrary string, right?

Comment: Its a URI rather than a URL I think. URIs identify and URLs locate so it doesnt need to be functioning in this case.

Comment: @HansEkbrand Well, the namespace URI _is_ functional, it's just that its purpose is not what you thought it was. As has been said already, their function is to uniquely identify elements and attributes. And yes, it's an arbitrary string - until you have decided on a certain URI for your XML document - then, XPath expressions are bound to redeclare exactly this string.